# Right align second line in centered text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Sorry if the title isn't very clear, but I'm trying to figure out how to solve the following problem using CSS.

I have a text that should be shown in two different lines: imagine first line is "hello world" and second is "goodbye"

I'd need to show the text in this way, in the **center of the screen**:

```
hello world
    goodbye
```

I'm using this as first attempt but all I get is both lines centered. I'd need to have the second line aligned to the right.

```
div#logo {
    clear: both;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 0;
    margin: 1em auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could just make the "hello world" and "goodbye" in two separate `div`s, with a `style` of `margin: 0; padding: 0;`

Comment: Tried that, but the problem is that I need the second line to be aligned with respect to the first line.

Comment: Absolutely no jQuery? Pretty simple to accomplish with that.

Comment: No jQuery unfortunately. Requirement is doing this with CSS only.

Comment: And I assume you aren't able to set a specific width on that div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the width of the text inside the logo div it's a relatively simple thing to do, if you don't I do believe you're going to need jQuery to accomplish it.

```
<div id="logo">
    <p class="right">
    hello world<br />
    goodbye
    </p>
</div>


div#logo {
clear: both;
padding: 1em;
border: 0;
margin: 1em auto;
text-align: center;
width: 75%;
position:relative;
height:100px; 
}

.right{
position:absolute;
width:90px;
margin-left:-45px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/QnGDs/1/

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="logo"><p>First line<br />Remaining Text</p></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#logo {text-align:center;}
div#logo p {display:inline-block; text-align:right;}
```

Comment: Maybe a better option: <code><div id="logo"><center>First line</center> Remining Text</div></code>

Comment: @Dan: The question is wrong. If undarstand correctly reading comments below your question you need just right aligned text on two lines to be centered inside some container? This can be really easy acheived, just the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution: Have your paragraph aligned to the right with the `max-width` set to the width of the first-line, the second line will automatically break and be aligned to the right.

**html**

```
<div id="logo">
    <p>Hello World goodbye!</p>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**css**

```
#logo
{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#logo p
{
    max-width:80px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

​
Here's a functional [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHUJp/1/)

Comment: Doesn't address the centred in page part.

Answer (score -1):

If you put that text in a p element like:

```
<div id="logo">
<p>Hello world <br />goodbye</p>
</div>
```

And apply the following css:

```
div#logo
{
width: 75%;
margin: 0px auto;
}

#logo p
{
text-align: right;
}
```

I believe that is what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't, as this will not put the two lines aligned in the center of the screen, but rather in the xx-75% range.

Answer (score -1):

How about putting your second line in some other container and then push it towards the right

```
<div id="logo">
hello world<br/>
<span class="right">goodbye</span>
</div>


div#logo {
clear: both;
padding: 1em;
border: 0;
margin: 1em auto;
text-align: center;
width: 75%;
}

.right {
text-align: right;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: I need second line to show right aligned with last letter of first line

Answer (score -1):

only in case the width is known or pre-set

```
<div class="wrapper">  
    <div class="first-line">hello word</div>  
    <div class="second-line">goodbye</div>  
</div>`

<style>  
    .wrapper{ width: 70px; margin: 0 auto;}  
    .first-line { float: left;}  
    .second-line{ float: right;}  
</style>`
```

**Explanation**
.wrapper:

1. width - must be known and pre-set not necessarily in the css you can use in-line style
2. margin - top and bottom 0px where left and right equally balanced

.first-line:

1. float - to the left

.second-line

1. float - to the right

Please check the link to see working example
http://jsfiddle.net/pQTBz/

Comment: Doesn't show both lines center aligned, and second line isn't right aligned either with respect to first line: http://jsfiddle.net/FTda6/